# Examples of Fat-Shattering Dimension

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, computing-over-reals

What are some good examples for analysis of a class's Fat-Shattering dimension?

By ([Alon et al](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/learn3.pdf)) I know that the Fat-Shattering Dimension characterizes the learnability of real-valued function classes but I didn't find any proper examples of function class with a proof for a bound on the Fat-Shattering Dimension of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $L$-Lipschitz functions on a metric space $(X,\rho)$ with $\epsilon$-packing number $M(\epsilon)$, the $\gamma$-shattering dimension is $M(2\gamma/L)$, as proved here:
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6867374/

Comment: Are there any more examples?

Comment: The $\gamma$-shattering dimension of hyperplanes on a ball of radius $R$ is $(R/\gamma)^2$.

Comment: Care for a proof or s link to one? :-)

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.42.6950

Comment: See Theorem 1.6